# Convert java code file into tag file

Tags: java, file

How to convert a java code  file into a tag file ?

> A tag file contain a java commands.

Comment: What kind of tags? Custom JSP tag library?

Comment: Can you say what you mean by "java commands" or a "tag file" can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be using the jtags: http://www.fleiner.com/jtags/
It is in beta phase, but it can be given a chance.